# Yum is broken after deleting /lib64/python3.6 on CentOS 8

Tags: linux, rhel, python, yum, rpm

I accidentally removed /lib64/python3.6 which was installed with yum previously. Yum is now broken and i cant install packages. I am running on CentOS8. I installed python3.10 from source. I have tried installing python3.6 from source and coping python3.6 directory to /lib64 but the make file doesn't pass the test.When I run yum command i get this error. When i also run dnf i get the same output.

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f306e54cb80 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can i fix this? Time is not on my side. Whats the quickest way to fix this. I am new to CentOs.

Comment: You will have to install Python 3.6 and all dependencies using `rpm`.   This link relates to CentOS 6, but the process outlined is the same.  https://serverfault.com/questions/337549/how-to-undo-yum-remove-python

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it

Comment: I have tried intalling from source so that I could just replace the /lib64/python3.6 file that i deleted but i still get errors from the 'make'

Comment: Reinstalling the system is probably the easiest route forward. You have backups, right?

Comment: Not sure how do i check.It is not my server.

Comment: Could i intead completely remove the system python and reinstall it?

Comment: Or point the system to use my python3.10 installed from the source?

Comment: Do you still have the installation media? If yes: mount it. Run `rpm -qa | grep yum`. From that output pick the `yum-<version-mumble>` and run `rpm -qp yum-<version-mumble>.rpm --requires` (note how I tacked on `rpm` to the mumble!).  Then cd into `/path/to/cd/Packages` and install *ALL* the files listed as required in the previous rpm queries output: `rpm -i <list of rpms>` ...